# How to properly clear terminal history in Node.js

Tags: node.js, linux, macos, command-line-interface

I'm creating my own cli (for my use only) and I would like a method "clear" that works like macos' (or linux's) "reset" (tput reset) command. Mainly the fact that it clears all text in the terminal even previous text that is outside of the terminal viewport. Any Ideas?

I've tried child_process' `exec()` and I've tried methods that "clear" all and move the cursor to 0,0. But neither of these do what I want.

Answer (score -1):

You can clear bash shell history via this command.

```
history -c && history -w
```

Comment: If you read the question, I'd like it to work like the unix command ``reset``. This answer does not help me.

Comment: reset clear terminal contents but history -c && history -w will clear bash shell history.

Comment: I don't want to clear terminal history. I want a command LIKE RESET. Clearing the terminal contents including that which is outside of the viewport.